# Symfony4 - Where process the payload in restful api

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I have been working on a restful api, I would like to know where should I process the payload after been validated. Right now it look something like this:

```
// src/Controller/ExampleController.php
public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    // the getPayload gonna return a object representing my data
    // already validate, ready to be processed
    $data = $this->getPayload()

    $exampleEntity = new ExampleEntity();
    $exampleEntity
        ->setUser($this->getUser())
        ->setBook($data->book);
    $manager->persist($exampleEntity);
    $manager->flush();

    return new JsonResponse($example->getResult());
}
```

I was adviced to create a service to process the data and don't use direct in the controller. I actually like to separate the data outside the controller, but then should I create a service for each controller? something like this:

```
// src/Controller/SomeController.php
public function create(Request $request, \App\Service\Example $example)
{
    // the getPayload gonna return a object representing my data
    // already validate, ready to be processed
    $data = $this->getPayload()
    $example->setPayload($data);
    $example->process();

    return new JsonResponse($example->getResult());
}
```

I have other question, should I validate identifiers, for example if I receive a json body passing the id of a book, if I create a new constraint to verify if the book exist it would require a query in the database (because i'm validating the payload automatically before it gets int he controller) and one more query later to actually create the relation. Example:

```
// src/Controller/ExampleController.php
public function create(
    Request $request,
    ExampleReposiry $repository,
    EntityManagerInterface $manager)
{
    // the getPayload gonna return a object representing my data
    // already validate, ready to be processed
    $data = $this->getPayload()

    $exampleEntity = new ExampleEntity();
    $exampleEntity
        ->setUser($this->getUser())
        // $data->book is only the id, not the actually object book
        // this is the second time query for the object, the fist
        // time was inside the custom constraint that validate
        // to see if the id pass is valid.
        ->setBook($repository->findBy(['id' => $data->book]));
    $manager->persist($exampleEntity);
    $manager->flush();

    return new JsonResponse($example->getResult());
}
```

Or instead of that I just assume that the id of the book pass is valid and if not I just throw an Exception?

The post that I follow to validate automatically the data [here](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/j196/automatically-serialising-and-validating-requests-in-symfony-json-apis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was adviced to create a service to process the data and don't use direct in the controller. I actually like to separate the data outside the controller, but then should I create a service for each controller?
>
> Or instead of that I just assume that the id of the book pass is valid and if not I just throw an Exception?

I would separate responsibilities as follows.

1. Create a `ExampleService` class (where business logic takes place) and inject it into `ExampleController`.
2. Pass you validated data-set to `ExampleService` class.
3. Check if the id of the book in DB. Throw an exception otherwise.
4. Create a `ExampleFactory` class (where data mapping takes place) and inject it into `ExampleService`.
5. Pass your data-set to `ExampleFactory` so that it returns `ExampleEntity` instance.
6. Call `persist` and `flush` on `ExampleEntity` instance. Assuming that you already injected `ExampleRepository` class into `ExampleService` class.

Then do whatever else you need to do and return `Response::HTTP_CREATED` in `ExampleController`.

Comment: Thanks again @BentCoder. I just got a little confused about ExempleFactory, why create a factory and not just instantiate the ExampleEntity directly in the ExampleService?

Comment: You are creating an object. Factory pattern is used for such cases in OOP so make use of patterns for specific cases. That's is the reason. It helps you separate concerns. By the way, I would suggest you to create Interface for your service and factory classes then use them for dependency injection rather than injecting the actual classes.

Comment: I just don't see the point in creating a factory if it will always instantiate the same object. Maybe because the example given it wasn't clear.

Comment: `I just don't see the point in creating a factory if it will always instantiate the same object.` - that is the purpose of Factory pattern. Anyway, it is up to programmer so we either do things with the OOP way or old school way. Your call.

Comment: Oh, I actually write it wrong, my english is kind of meh, what I meant was that I will always pass the same data without any variation to the factory to then instantiate the object. I think that would be ok when dealing with complex object that need many things done in the constructor, but in my case its a really plain object. So in the end it feels like thare's  no difference that creating a method that encapsulate the initiation of the object.

Answer (score 0):

This was my implementation base on what @BentCoder answered.
After pass the whole day at work thinking factory or no factory ? I end up trying use factory pattern because:

- it's smart follow advice of more experienced programmers (or give a try at least)
- better understanding of a pattern
- try out new things (it's a side project so it's ok mess up)

  ```
  // src/Controller/ExampleController.php
  public function create(\App\Service\Example $exampleService)
  {
      $exampleService->process($this->getPayload());
      // .. do something
  }

  // src/Service/Example.php
  public function process(App\Model\ExampleInterface $data)
  {
      // factory was receive via dependency injection in the constructor
      $objects = $this->factory->create($data);
      // .. do something
  }

  // src/Model/Example/Create.php
  class Create implements App\Model\ExampleInterface
  {
      public $property1;
      public $property2;
  }

  // src/Model/Example/Update.php
  class Update implements App\Model\ExampleInterface
  {
      public $property2;
  }

  // src/Factory/ExampleFactory.php
  public function create(App\Model\ExampleInterface $data)
  {
      if ($data instanceof App\Model\Example\Create::class) (
          // .. return a array of instantiated object
      } elseif ($data instanceof App\Model\Example\Update::class) {
          // .. returm only one object
      }
  }
  ```